# What is the VB.net equivalent to VB6 MSComm.CommPort?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am converting a VB6 application to a VB.net application. I have been able to convert all of the code properly other than lines calling the `MSComm.CommPort` property. I cannot find an equivalent to this property anywhere.

All of information I have found on converting from VB6 to VB.NET provides a code example [like this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5d3c8089-215c-4aab-a644-edb607206053/serial-port-from-vb6-to-vbnet), but it never explain where the `MSComm.CommPort` control is dealt with.

If anyone can tell me the VB.NET Comm Port class equivalent, or point me in the direction of a proper explanation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you are replacing it with a `SerialPort` component? Use `.PortName`

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't clarify. Thanks

Comment: Provides a property and a method for accessing the computer's serial ports.

Remarks
The My.Computer.Ports object provides a straightforward entry point for accessing the .NET Framework serial port class, SerialPort. 

Tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go have a read of this tutorial http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/37361-serial-port-communication-in-vbnet/